# Restart ibid after new chapter

Tags: biblatex

So I want that after a new chapter there is the full citation and then only the ibid. I'm using `biblatex` with the `authoryear-ibid` style.

```
\newbibmacro*{cite}{%
    \global\boolfalse{cbx:loccit}%
    \iffieldundef{shorthand}
        {\ifthenelse{\ifciteibid\AND\NOT\iffirstonpage}
            {\usebibmacro{cite:ibid}}
            {\ifthenelse{\ifnameundef{labelname}\OR\iffieldundef{labelyear}}
                {\usebibmacro{cite:label}%
                \setunit{\printdelim{nonameyeardelim}}}
                {\printnames{labelname}%
                \setunit{\printdelim{nameyeardelim}}}%
            \usebibmacro{cite:labelyear+extrayear}}}
        {\usebibmacro{cite:shorthand}}}
```

So I found the above in the `authoryear-ibid.cbx` and to my understanding I need to change the `\iffirstonpage` to something like `\ifnewchapter`. However I don't know how to create a `\ifnewchapter` macro or how to overwrite `\iffirstonpage`.

So the picture on the left shows what I get and the one on the right what I want:

[image]
[image]

And here is the MWE:

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage[style=authoryear-ibid]{biblatex}
\bibliography{example}
\begin{document}
    \chapter{Example 1}
    Text (\cite{Johnson99})

    More Text (\cite{Johnson99})
    \chapter{Example 2}
    Text (\cite{Johnson99})
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You want the option `citereset=chapter`. Strictly speaking that option resets more than just the 'ibidem' tracking at each new chapter, but for the style `authoryear-ibid` only 'ibidem' tracking is affected, for other styles this broader resetting might even be desirable.

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage[style=authoryear-ibid, citereset=chapter]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}
\begin{document}
  \chapter{Example 1}
  Text \parencite{sigfridsson}

  More Text \parencite{sigfridsson}

  \chapter{Example 2}
  Text \parencite{sigfridsson}
\end{document}
```